# Analogue of $S^2$ and $SO(3)$ in hyperbolic coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

both the two sphere and $SO(3)$ can be parametrized using spherical coordinates. I was wondering what kinds of manifolds one gets when one replaces in the charts the cos by cosh and the sin by sinh and considers angles over the reals.

Is there a name for these two objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "spherical coordinates" means
$$
X(u, v) = (\cos u \cos v, \cos \sin v, \cos v),
$$
the "hyperbolic analogue" would be
$$
X(u, v) = (x, y, z) = (\cosh u \cosh v, \cosh u \sinh v, \sinh u),
$$
whose component functions satisfy $x^{2} - y^{2} = \cosh^{2} u$ (with $x \geq 1$), and therefore
$$
x^{2} - y^{2} - z^{2} = \cosh^{2} u - \sinh^{2} u = 1,\quad x \geq 1.
$$
This is one-half of a hyperboloid of two sheets (a well-known model of the hyperbolic plane, see for example Patrick Ryan's *Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry*). Geometrically, you can think of the surface as swept out by the branch of the hyperbola $(\cosh v, \sinh v, 0)$ under a [boost transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Mathematical_formulation) in the $(y, z)$-plane, the hyperbolic analogue of a rotation.

Offhand I'd expect the "hyperbolic analogue" of $SO(3)$ to be [$SO^{+}(2, 1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#The_Lie_group_SO.2B.283.2C1.29) (the identity component of the isometry group of the Minkowski space $\mathbf{R}^{2,1}$) because of [Wick rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation), but I haven't carefully checked.